# In Chrome min-height: 100% along with flexbox’s align-items: center; doesn't make items vertically center

Tags: css, flexbox, cross-browser, vertical-alignment

- Using ***Chrome***, if a container has **min_height and display:flex**; the items inside it will not change adding **align-items:center;** while it works by giving a fixed height.
- Using ***Firefox*** the problem does not arise.

Is there a possibility to center elements vertically in chrome when the container has a min-height and flexbox?

**HTML**

```
<fieldset class="container_difficulty container">
            <legend class="legend">Difficulty</legend>
            <div>
              <input type="radio" id="easy" name="difficulty" value="easy">
              <label class="button" for="easy">Easy</label>                  
            </div>
            <div>
              <input type="radio" id="medium" name="difficulty" value="medium" checked> 
              <label class="button" for="medium">Medium</label>                                 
            </div>
            <div>
              <input type="radio" id="hard" name="difficulty" value="hard">
              <label class="button" for="hard">Hard</label>                  
            </div>
</fieldset>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{    
  position: relative;
  display: flex;   
  justify-content: center;   
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
}
fieldset.container{
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 20vh; //Works in Firefox, needs "height: 20vh" in Chrome

  background-color: hsl(0 50% 0% / .5);
  border: 1px solid hsl(0 0% 60% / .5);
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 hsla(236, 19%, 48%, 0.249);

  margin: 1.5em auto;
  padding: 1em;
  padding-top: 2em;

  text-align: center;

  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  gap: .5rem;
}
```

*Chrome vs Firefox display:* https://i.stack.imgur.com/jip7d.jpg

Comment: The issue is related to the fieldset element, if it is not mandatory in your HTML code change it to a simple div for example and it will work

Answer (score 0):

`fieldset` doesn't work with flexbox in Chrome, see [this](https://gist.github.com/LeaVerou/ba3e221380020f32427e066d8185f5ff) for reference.

Comment: Why if I set "height" instead of "min-height" everything works?

Comment: Ha, interesting! So it still works! Different browsers, different algorithms... So Chrome needs to explicitly specify the height so that it can calculate the alignment... Let's take note. Thanks for the great question!